# Vertically centering with Tables

Tags: css, html-table, vertical-alignment

I have an iframe and a div inside a container. The two of them need to be vertically centered. After reading a few posts on tables to center, I gave it a try but to no avail. The iframe continues to stick to the top left border even though I have the iframe 'display' property set to 'table-cell' & 'vertical-align' to 'middle'.

The HTML code:

```
<!-- the container div -->
<div id="iframe_r_container">

<!-- iframe -->
            <iframe id="iframing" src="mannequin.html" frameborder="0" ></iframe>

<!--div-->      <div id="right_container">
                <div id="user_credit">
                    <h1><a href="#">Username</a></h1><br />
                     has <span id="credits">20,000</span> credits.
                </div>

                <div> <button id="template_button"><img src="images/Coutallure-WebApp/template_button.png" /><span>Templates</span></button> </div>
            </div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
/* START OF IFRAME_R_CONTAINER */
#iframe_r_container {
    position: absolute;
    display: table;
    top: 48px;
    bottom: 38px;
    width: 960px;   
}

/* START OF IFRAME */
#iframing {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
/* END OF IFRAME */


/* START OF RIGHT CONTAINER */
#right_container {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    width: 113px;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

I have been stuck at this for half a day today so any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the `display: table-cell` structure, but, wouldn't you have to enclose it within `display: table` and `display: table-row` ?

Comment: _Never_ use tables for layout. Only for displaying tabular data :)

Comment: Good point Kyle but I read on Stackoverflow itself on centreing vertically with tables so was trying to figure it out. Cheers to you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using another technique than table-cell centering, you can try something like this :

```
#iframe_r_container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    bottom: 38px;
    width: 960px;
}

/* START OF IFRAME */
#iframing {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -240px;
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
    float: left;
}
/* END OF IFRAME */


/* START OF RIGHT CONTAINER */
#right_container {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    height: 113px;
    margin-top: -57px;
    margin-left: 670px;
    width: 113px;

}
```

It works here on my FF/mac but you'd have to test it on other browser.

To center #right_container, you'd have to give it a heigh (here 113px) and set the negative margin-top accordingly.

Also, you may want to give a min-height: 640px to #iframe_r_container to avoid the iframe overflowing outside of its container.

Comment: Thank you LapinLove404, thats awesome and made sense too. Best,

Answer (score 1):

Adding "height" to your containers should do it. Just adding it to your iframe container worked for me in FF on my Mac.

```
#iframe_r_container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    bottom: 38px;
    width: 960px;
    height:480px;   
}
```

(Note: Internet Explorer 8 (and higher) supports the property values "inline-table", "run-in", "table", "table-caption", "table-cell", "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-row", "table-row-group", and "inherit" only if a !DOCTYPE is specified.)

Comment: @Kevin margin: 0 auto = No margin top/center left and right. margin: auto auto won't work unless there is a height attribute assigned to a parent element, ie. #iframe_r_container

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what are you trying to achieve, but just from reading your post - you cannot try centering element itself with some align property, this must be property of its parent element. You should try that margin, i think this is the right property to work with.

Answer (score 0):

try these settings:

```
/* START OF IFRAME_R_CONTAINER */
#iframe_r_container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    bottom: 38px;
    width: 960px;   
}

/* START OF IFRAME */
#iframing {
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
/* END OF IFRAME */


/* START OF RIGHT CONTAINER */
#right_container {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 113px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The attribute `margin: 0 auto;` will (hopefully) center your iframe and other div inside the container. Not tested but give it a try.